# How to fix google page speed insights issue?

Tags: caching, css-js-aggregation

I'm facing issues on my every drupal site when i test my website in [Google page speed insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) . I have configured Advagg module and [followed](https://www.northstudio.com/blog/increase-your-drupal-site-pagespeed-score-part-2-advagg) but not succeed.Issues are below:

1. Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content.
2. Leverage browser caching.
3. Enable compression.

Sometimes (1) can be fixed by advagg setting but (2) and (3) need configuration in .htaccess. Can anybody provide me solution?

Answer (score 1):

With [AdvAgg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) enabled go to the status report page `admin/reports/status`. It should offer advice on how to fix gzip and browser caching for css/js aggregates. Also see the [readme](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/advagg/tree/README.txt#n535), under troubleshooting there are some tips for getting apache to do what you need it to.

If advagg doesn't report any issues then check and see what kinds of resources google is complaining about in terms of browser caching (.jpg) and compression (fonts). Also remember that if these are coming from an external domain (google analytics) there isn't a lot you can do as you don't control that server.

Edit: Guide here - https://groups.drupal.org/node/517292. It's the [AdvAgg Readme](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/advagg/tree/README.txt) file as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you told you can Handle Aggregation of JS and CSS by [AdvAgg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) but for *Enable compression* and *Leverage browser caching* Read this article about [Leverage Browser Caching for Images, CSS and JS](https://www.siteground.com/kb/leverage-browser-caching/).

Add these lines to your `.htacess` file.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Also, you can try

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$"> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public" </FilesMatch>
```